# Relative Path setting in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, filereader

I am trying to access config.xml file from my JAVA program. But its showing me "File Not Found".
Here is my project structure. I am using eclipse.

[image]

So now I want to read "conf/config-file.xml". How should I do that? 
Note:

- I cannot change project structure.
- 'conf' and 'bin' they ain't under '/root'.They are under just one common project directory.

Please help
Thank you!!

Comment: Try get the path of your jar file, maybe [this post][1] will be helpful.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "user.dir" property of Java System Variable, you can access your file.

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "conf" + File.separator +  "config-file.xml"
```

Comment: thanks.. this works. but I have to change my Eclipse my default setup location.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the java program from Eclipse, the default work directory (current directory) is the project directory like "C:\workspace\myproject"(or /workspace/myproject on Linux). To open the conf/config-file.xml, the following codes should work.

```
File configFile = new File("conf/config-file.xml");
System.out.println(configFile.getAbsolutePath()); // Just for testing
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure but try this>> ../conf/config-file.xml